# Typescript function return string array

Tags: javascript, typescript

My console statement does not print the length  of the string array. If I print list within the for loop it does show data.

```
public getText = (items: any) => {

  let list: string[] = [];

    for (let item of items) {
      list.push(item);
    }

  console.log('list ' + list);

  return list;
};
```

Also how can I call the function?

let items = ct.Text(titles);

If I try to print items is does not print anything.

Comment: You're logging `list` instead of `list.length`

Comment: Also, you're pushing a variable called `text` into the list. Instead of `item` i guess.

Comment: @FrankModica updated above code

Answer (score -2):

```
 getText(items:any){ 
  let list: string[] = [];
  for (let item of items) {
   list.push(item);
  }
  console.log('list length ' + list.length);

  return list.length;
 }
```

Maybe length is not an attribute  and is a function, in this case, you need to write

```
 list.length()
```

To call the function:

```
 let tamano = getText(items);
```

Comment: `length` is not a function in the JS standard library.